# Using jQuery UI ThemeRoller Custom Theme Implementation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, themeroller

I just use [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) and download the theme I couldn't implement it
I have tried to import files, however while I add an input for date picker it is still only textbox... How to use this I only need "Datepicker" What am I doing wrong ?
Appreciate any help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Content/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <input id="date" type="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
   $(function() {
      $('#date').datepicker();
         });
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Everything looks in order. Out of curiosity, move all of the css file references to the top, before all js files. This shouldn't make a difference to your specific problem though.

Comment: Strange, I just import
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
and it works :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are enough to make the custom ThemeRoller work(and of course add the images)

```
<link href="~/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Hope it will help to others who is seeking for jQuery UI Custom ThemeRoller Implementation.